Given three points on a line, construct a circle through two of these points and a certain tangent through the third point
I'm given a line $AB$ and a point $C$ on that line such that $B$ lies between $A$ and $C$. An acute angle $\alpha$ is constructed from vertex $B$. One side of this angle is ray $BA$, another side of this angle (let's denote it as $l$) is not on the line $AB$.

I want to construct a circle through points $A$ and $B$ which passes the ray $l$ at such point $K$ that $CK$ is tangent to that circle.

My thoughts:

I'm seeking for a circumcircle of a triangle $\triangle ABK$, and the circumcenter of this triangle lies on the point of intersection of its perpendicular bisectors. I can easily construct a perpendicular bisector of $AB$ but no clue how to get any of two other ones.
The circumcircles of $\triangle ABK$ and $\triangle CBK$ have common points $B$ and $K$. That may come in handy.
According to the alternate segment theorem, angles $\angle BAK$ and $\angle CKB$ should be equal.

The main problem is that I cannot construct the correct point $K$.

Interesting, but what have you tried?

Added my thoughts on the matter.

Hint: Power of a point tells you the length $CK$. Then you need to find a way to construct that length.

You were almost there…
Hint:
Let $\angle BAK=\angle CKB=\theta$
So $\angle KCB=\alpha-\theta$ (using the $\triangle KBC$)
Now, $\angle CKA=180-\angle KAC -\angle KCA=180-\alpha$
Having found $\angle CKA$, can you now construct the point $K$?

Interactive Geogebra view
